# Selenium - Filter/ loop through elements to check for specific text

Tags: java, selenium, for-loop, selenium-webdriver

As Java is not my "best language" I would like to ask for support. I'm trying to validate if element from the list contains a specific value.

1. I'm having element which locates at least 5+ elements
2. I'm trying to get that element:
   eg.         `List<WebElement> elementsList = getWebElementList(target, false);`
3. I'm trying to validate if specific text is a part of the taken list. By doing something like:

   `elementsList.contains(valueToCheck);`

it does not work...

also I found a way of using `stream()` method which looks more/less like this but I'm having troubles with continuation:
`elementsList.stream().filter(WebElement::getText.....`

---

Can you please explain me how lists are handled in Java in modern/ nowadays way? In C# I was mostly using LINQ but don't know if Java has similar functionality.

Comment: Is there some reason you can't add the text as part of an XPath and find the right element from the start? This will be faster than finding a handful of elements, looping through each to find the one that contains the desired text, and then proceeding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you get the element list.You can try something like that. this will return true or false.

```
elementsList.stream().anyMatch(e -> e.getText().trim().contains("specficelementtext")
```

Comment: Something similar to mentioned LINQ, works perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can not apply `contains()` method directly on a list of WebElement objects.
This method can be applied on String object only.
You also can not extract text directly from list of WebElement objects.
What you can do is:
Get the list of WebElements matching the given locator, iterate over the WebElements in the list extracting their text contents and checking if that text content contains the desired text, as following:

```java
public static boolean waitForTextInElementList(WebDriver driver, By locator, String expectedText, int timeout) {
    try {
        List<WebElement> list;
        for (int i = 0; i < timeout; i++) {
            list = driver.findElements(locator);
            for (WebElement element : list) {
                if (element.getText().contains(expectedText)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            i++;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ConsoleLogger.error("Could not find the expected text " + expectedText + " on specified element list" + e.getMessage());
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout); I think this object wait has never been used in your code although it has been created. Also, in the same line of code WebDriverWait constructor will not accept integer, I think. Please check.